# Missing json information using python

Tags: python, json

I am struggling to get some json information to appear in a dataframe column

The information is `'data_at': 1619293080600`

Here is what I have so far:

```
requestT = requests.get('https:............)
json_dataT = json.loads(requestT.text)

print(json_dataT)
```

Output:

```
{'data_at': 1619293080600, 'data': {'london_NW': {'loc_postcode': 'NW1', 'loc_name': 'camden_twn', 'ave_price': '1061227.00'}, 'london_SW': {'loc_postcode': 'SW1', 'loc_name': 'victoria', 'ave_price': '1878130.00'}}}
```

I then transform this into a dataframe via the following method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_dataT)
dfNormal = json_normalize(df['data'])
```

However, I lose the 'data_at' information which is a timestamp that I want in column 0. What I get is the following:

```
        loc_postcode          loc_name              ave_price
0                NW1        camden_twn             1061227.00
1                SW1          victoria             1878130.00
```

How can I get the 'data_at' (timestamp) to appear as the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the desired result is to "normalize" `json_dataT`, as `json_dataT['data'].keys()` is not present in the desired result.

Specifically, "drop" the level w/ `json_dataT['data'].keys()`:

```py
>>> json_dataT['data'] = list(json_dataT['data'].values())
```

Then, apply `json_normalize` to get the dataframe:

```py
>>> df_normal = json_normalize(json_dataT, record_path='data', meta='data_at')
>>> df_normal
  loc_postcode    loc_name   ave_price        data_at
0          NW1  camden_twn  1061227.00  1619293080600
1          SW1    victoria  1878130.00  1619293080600
```

Finally, reorder the columns to make `data_at` the first column:

```py
>>> cols = df_normal.columns.tolist()
>>> cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
>>> df_normal = df_normal[cols]
>>> df_normal
         data_at loc_postcode    loc_name   ave_price
0  1619293080600          NW1  camden_twn  1061227.00
1  1619293080600          SW1    victoria  1878130.00
```

Comment: Just saw this a few minutes ago. It worked like a charm. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way `df` is constructed, the index will not match with the result of your `.json_normalize()` operation -- it will be: `Index(['london_NW', 'london_SW'], dtype='object')`.
To get around this you can use `.reset_index()`, and then horizontally concatenate with `pd.concat()` with `axis=1`:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df_normal = pd.concat([df['data_at'],pd.json_normalize(df['data'])],axis=1)
```

Result:

```
In [63]: df_normal
Out[63]: 
         data_at loc_postcode    loc_name   ave_price
0  1619293080600          NW1  camden_twn  1061227.00
1  1619293080600          SW1    victoria  1878130.00
```

Comment: I get an error of TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable